# Find channel using partial name

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The scenario I need help with is this. I have several channels I want to send a message to whose names all end with the word “events” (pc events, Xbox events, etc).

Rather than typing the below code over and over again I’d like to find a way to search for all channels that include/end with the word events and then send a message to them.

```
const xboxEvents = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '111111111111111111')
const pcEvents = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '111111111111111111')
const psnEvents = bot.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === '111111111111111111')
xboxEvents.send(eventsEmbed)
pcEvents.send(eventsEmbed)
psnEvents.send(eventsEmbed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) the collection by the channel's name and use the [`.endsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) method to check if the channel's name ends with a certain string. As `.filter()` returns a new collection, you can iterate over it and send a message on each channel.

You can also check if the channel's [`type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=type) is either `text` or `news` as only these have a `.send()` method.

```js
const channels = bot.channels.cache.filter(
  (channel) =>
    channel.name.endsWith('event') && ['text', 'news'].includes(channel.type)
);

channels.each((channel) => channel.send(eventsEmbed).catch(console.error));
```

If you want to check if the channel name includes the string "event", you can use [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead of `.endsWith()`.

Comment: Got this error, tried fixing in in several ways but nothing ..................................................
        channels.each((channel) => channel.send(eventsEmbed).catch(console.error));
                                           ^

TypeError: channel.send is not a function
    at \commands\postevents.js:38:44

Comment: You can check the channel type, I've just updated the code above.

Comment: Perfect. Checking the channel type fixed it.