# How to know if the channel name includes the word ticket

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a ticket system, but it is only based on buttons. So I want to add a /close that allows me to close the channel, but I can't find a way to make it detect if the channel is called "ticket-" then transcribe it and close it.

I tried using but it does not work:

```
const channel = interaction.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "ticket-");
```

Comment: Is `ticket-` the full name, or just a part of it? If it's a part of the full name, maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431647/find-channel-using-partial-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to find all channels that contains `ticket-` prefix, you can not directly compare `channel.name` because then you are trying to find something that fully match given value.
To find a string that start with some prefix you should use ***[`.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)*** method

```js
const someStrings = ['aaTEST', 'bbTEST', 'ccTEST', 'aaSOME'];
const onlyAA = someStrings.filter(item => item.startsWith('aa'));
console.log(onlyAA);
```